# Find the correlation given standard deviations, means and one fitted (predicted) value

Tags: regression, correlation, self-study

> A student got 88 in his first exam, which had mean score of 64 with SD 8. He missed the second exam in which the mean score was 45 and SD was 5. The professor used regression to award him a prorated mark of 55. What was the correlation of marks between the two exams?

Am I doing this right?

$$
\hat{z}_y = r z_x
$$

and I calculated respective $\hat{z}$ values with the formula

$$
\frac{x-\bar{x}}{s_x}
$$

for $x$ and $y$ (predicted) in this case.

The answer that I got is 0.66, is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps you could start it off by describing what attempts you have made on this question and telling us where you are stuck or uncertain.

Comment: I just don't know how to approach this question

Comment: Consider reviewing what you know about regression. If you were *told* the correlation, as well as given most of the data in the question--$88$, $64$, $8$, $45$, and $5$--could you compute the prorated value of $55$? If not, what additional information do you feel you would need?

Comment: I tried to calculate z hat sub y = r z sub x. I calculate z sub x and z sub y from standard deviation and mean given in the formula. But i am not sure whatever i did is right.

Comment: That's good: why don't you show that in your question. By the way, we support $\TeX$ markup to make equations readable: for more information, see the help panel at your right while editing. As a start, right-click on this equation to see how the markup works: $\hat{z}_y = r z_x$.

Comment: Well done!  I figure the answer is $2/3$ and that's pretty close to your $0.66$.